# Calling a function without passing arguments meteor app

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

Working through discover meteor (page 92), one section covers this code:

```
Posts.allow({
    update: ownsDocument,
    remove: ownsDocument
});

ownsDocument = function(userId, doc) {
    return doc && doc.userId === userId;
}
```

The code itself as you may have guessed only allows a user to update/remove their own posts depending on if "ownsDocument" returns true or false. What I don't get how simply calling "ownsDocument" successfully accomplishes anything when it doesn't appear to be passing arguments to the function. How can ownsDocument return true or false when it doesn't appear Posts.allow is passing the userId/doc when it's being called?

EDIT: removed stray semicolon in example code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [...]  when it doesn't appear Posts.allow is passing the userId/doc when it's being called?

And where does it get called?

In your example, `ownsDocument` is not called *at all*. All you are doing is configuring which functions should be called in the `update` and `remove` case.

The functions are called *somewhere else* and *at a different time*, and there they will be passed the right arguments.

---

It's just like with event handlers. `foo.onclick = bar;` doesn't call `bar`. It assigns a reference to function to `foo.onclick`, so that the function can be called *some time later*. And at that moment, the function will be passed an event object.

Answer (score 1):

Meteor automatically passes the `userId` and `doc` arguments to whatever function object you assign to the `update` and `remove` keys passed to `allow`. The code you posted works the same as:

```
Posts.allow({
    update: function(userId, doc) {
        return doc && doc.userId === userId;
    },
    remove: function(userId, doc) {
        return doc && doc.userId === userId;
    }
});
```

The `ownsDocument` function doesn't get called in your code. The `allow` function informs Meteor to call that function any time a `Post` is updated or removed.