# From where does Meteor's Deny / Allow callbacks receive their parameter contents from?

Tags: meteor

I'm going through the Microscope book (again) and I'm trying to figure out where the Allow and Deny callbacks are getting their parameters from.

posts.js in collections folder:

```
Posts = new Meteor.Collection('posts');

Posts.allow({
    update: ownsDocument,
    remove: ownsDocument
});

Posts.deny({
    update: function(userId, post, fieldNames){
        return (_.without(fieldNames, 'url', 'title').length > 0);
    }
});
```

permissions.js in lib folder

```
ownsDocument = function(userId, doc){
    return doc && doc.userId === userId;
}
```

Say that a user invokes

```
Posts.update("postID234232", {objectTo: insert}, function(){//callback} );
```

`Posts.allow` and `Posts.deny` are then run.

1. Where does the `ownsDocument` function get the contents for the `userId` and `doc` parameters from?
2. Where does the `update` key in `Posts.deny` get the contents for the `userId`, `post`, and `fieldNames` from?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling a function without passing arguments meteor app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24112174/calling-a-function-without-passing-arguments-meteor-app)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1) Where does the ownsDocument function get the contents for the userId
>   and doc parameters from?

The `userId` is globally available in meteor on both the client and the server via `Meteor.userId()`, so `ownsDocument` is called with the current connected user who wants to perform a CRUD operation on the collection. This parameter is passed for convenience because in the `allow/deny` callback one could use `Meteor.userId()` to access the current user.

The doc parameter is the document impacted by the insert/update/remove, you have to keep in mind that allow/deny callback rules are executed within a collection CRUD operation so we have access to the actual document that the client is trying to modify.

> 2) Where does the update key in Posts.deny get the contents for the
>   userId, post, and fieldNames from?

When the client invokes Collection.update, it is passed what is called a mongo modifier object which lets you specify which fields in the collection you want to modify.
The `fieldNames` parameter contains the top-level fields names that the client is willing to modify, take this update call as an example :

```
Posts.update(postId,{
  $set:{
    title:"New title !"
  }
});
```

The update method will extract `"title"` as a top-level field the client wants to modify and will pass it to the allow/deny rules.

Here is pseudo-code for what the update method of Meteor.Collection could do to compute the parameters passed to the allow/deny rules, this is not actual meteor code and just provided as an explanation.

```
Meteor.Collection.prototype.update = function(selector, modifier, ...){
  // get a cursor of documents that should be impacted by the update
  var impactedDocuments = this.find(selector);
  // extract top-level fields names from the modifer [1]
  var fieldNames = _.keys(modifier.$set);
  // iterate over impacted documents
  impactedDocuments.forEach(function(impactedDocument){
    // iterate over "validators" (Meteor internal name for allow/deny rules)
    _.each(this._validators.update.allow, function(updateAllowRule){
      // call the allow rule with computed parameters
      updateAllowRule(Meteor.userId(), impactedDocument, fieldNames);
    });
  });
}
```

When you define an allow rule via

```
Collection.allow({
  update:function(userId, doc, fieldNames, modifier){
    // ...
  }
});
```

Meteor appends this function to `Collection._validators.allow.update`

[1] http://underscorejs.org/#keys

Comment: Awesome! The function called by `updateAllowRule(Meteor.userId(),impactedDocument,fieldNames);` is what I was looking for.

Comment: updateAllowRule does not call any function, it IS one of the callback functions you can pass to Collection.allow

Comment: I meant that the line `updateAllowRule(Meteor.userId(),impactedDocument,fieldNames);` is calling the `updateAllowRule` function.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so after some reading it appears that Meteor automatically passes the `userId` and `doc` arguments to whatever function object is assigned to the `update` and `remove` keys passed to allow or deny.

So, a very important take-away (I think):

'userId' and 'doc' MUST be in this specific order. I can re-write `ownsDocument` to something like this:

```
ownsDocument = function(theCurrentUsersId, document){
    return document && document.theCurrentUsersId === theCurrentUsersId;
}
```

but the user's ID must be before the document.

I couldn't do:

```
ownsDocument = function(document, theCurrentUsersId){
    return document && document.theCurrentUsersId === theCurrentUsersId;
}
```